# Excel VBA Is it possible to pass the ActiveCell or ActiveCell.Address as a param?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to pass a specific ActiveCell or even the ActiveCell.Address down to another Sub().

Function that has the ActiveCell I need is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Trim(TextBox1.Value) = "" Then

    MsgBox "No Value detected"
Else
    Debug.Print "ActiveCell on ButtonClick: " & ActiveCell.Address         ' ACTIVECELL IS CORRECT HERE
    MsgBox TextBox1.Value     ' good
    ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
    ReadDataFromAnotherWorkBookSO (ActiveCell.Address)              ' here is the Function that needs the ActiveCell.Address
End If

End Sub
```

Here is the Function Head() of the Function that needs the ActiveCell.Address :

```
Sub ReadDataFromAnotherWorkBookSO(ActCell As Range)       ' I expect the Address in here
```

Later on in that Function (ReadDataFromAnotherWorkBookSO) I want to take my ActCell and set it Active so I can change some .Offset() Values in the Sheet thats why I need the Address because ActiveCell is not the same anymore inside the function (ReadDataFromAnotherWorkBookSO).

I need to know how to properly use the passed ActiveCell.Address because currently it does not get passed through.

Thanks Faded~

Comment: Just use: `ReadDataFromAnotherWorkBookSO ActiveCell`. Note that there are no brackets used.

Comment: @Rory Okay thanks Rory passing down the ActiveCell without Brackets seems to work beacuse inside the Function I can get the ActCell.Address and it gives me the right one - Thanks for now!

Answer (score 1):

`.Address` is a string data type. Your function param expects a range.

So just pass `ActiveCell` instead of `ActiveCell.Address`.

Your second function can then get any parameter of the passed range object, including its address.